# .NET custom authorize attribute (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, controller

In certain Controller I have CRUD methods. In order to access these methods user needs to be logged in. This is why I used `[Authorize]` attribute for this controller. Now I need additional attribute which would check if item that user wants to view/delete/update belongs to him.

Is it possible and recommended to do this with attribute or you would suggest using check methods inside each method? If you suggest using attribute, could you please provide me some links/instructions?

EDIT:
Ofcourse, if attribute returns false than I don't want to redirect user to login page but show him an error message...

Comment: did you add the check in your controller methods in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a custom Authorize attribute, but it's much cleaner to put the logic inside your controller methods.

Comment: out of curiousity, why is it cleaner to put the logic inside the controller methods? Wouldnt you be checking for a similar thing everytime - do I own the resource, if not, throw 402, for example. That check would have to be added to every crud controller method, as opposed to one Authorize attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is related to the action being called (the controller class method). On that basis any attribute relating to the user's ownership of the object being manipulated (from your Model) should really be on the entity/class that the user is attempting to manipulate. You'll probably find it easier to validate the user within the Model method rather than using an attribute to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is possible, just google for 'Custom Authorize Attribute'.

But maybe it is better to query your database with something like this:

```
ContextOrSession.Query<Something>.Where(Something.Groups.Intersect(User.Groups).Count>0)
```

Comment: what is this query standing for? What is its purpose? Thanks!

Comment: If user tries to get item from db, just add filter or something to check his access to it. I can just give you some ideas. Also, what is included in term 'Owns' in your project?